# How to create a scrollable Column in Flutter that if it doesn't take up all the space it expands somewhere?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, alignment

I'm trying to create a scrollable column that has a widget at the bottom of the screen if it does not fill it up. However, if it does it scrolls.

First I tried with a simple `Column` with `MainAxisSize.max` and `Expand` with an empty `Container` which worked well until the column overflowed.

```dart
[...]

Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    MyWidget(),
    MyWidget(),
    [...],
    MyWidget(),
    Expand(child: Container()),
    ElevatedButton()
  ],
)
```

Then I searched and found the recommended solution for making a `Column` scrollable is the `SingleChildScrollView`. This made all of my widgets in the column disappear (which I am still unsure why) until I removed the `Expand` which although solved one problem, introduced another.

```dart
[...]

SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      MyWidget(),
      MyWidget(),
      [...],
      MyWidget(),
      // Expand(child: Container()),
      ElevatedButton()
    ],
  )
)
```

So my question is, how can I make a Column both scrollable and if it does not need all the space to expand so that the last child is at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: try use Spacer() ^^;

Comment: `Spacer` produces a similar problem as `Expand`, all widgets disappear

Answer (score 0):

`IntrinsicHeight` is too expensive to use but in this situation you have no choice. Try this:

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 400,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),          
    );
  })
```

in this example if you set height for blue `container` you will see the `scrollview` works, and if you use `Expanded` on it, it takes the available size.

Comment: What do you mean by too expensive?

Comment: check this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) @Forgotten-Storm

Comment: @Forgotten-Storm was it what you looking for?

Comment: It visibly slows down and it makes it scrollable even when it shouldn't so it takes up more space than needed